# Characterize edge-transitive Cayley Graphs

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-graph-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $S \subseteq G$ a symmetric subset. The Cayley graph $\Gamma(G,S)$ is always vertex-transitive, but it sufficient a simple example to show that it is not always edge-transitive (for example, take $\Gamma(S_3,\{ (12),(123),(132) \})$).

Is it possible to characterize edge-transitive Cayley graphs in terms of some properties of $S$?

Comment: Does an element of order 2 "look the same" as an element of order $97$?

Comment: Ok, I delete that part. I know for example $\Gamma(G,G \setminus 1)$ is always edge-transitive, it was only to give an idea (maybe a wrong one actually).

Comment: The number of orbits of edges is the same as the size of the generating set. You may label the edges by the corresponding generators and then the action is transitive on the edges with the same labels.

Comment: No, the number of $G$-orbits equals $|S|$, but $Aut(\Gamma(G,S))$ can be much larger than $G$. Look at the ciclic group $C_n$ and $Aut(\Gamma(C_n,\{C_n \setminus 0\})) \cong S_n$.